# HTML, CSS (Span TAG inside the Input)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to HTML,CSS and need some help. I am trying to put my clear icon inside the input tag across all browser. I have used bootstrap glyphicon-remove class. Below is my HTML tag

```
<input class="abc" type="text" maxlength="6"> 
<span class = " glyphicon glyphicon-remove " ng-show="showClearItem" ng-Click = "clearStuff()" ></span>
```

I can fix this using CSS but when i try this with different browser, clear button goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, it was MESS, complete mess, working on all three browsers. i tried lots of scenarios but nothing worked for me, either they are working on chrome and IE or on Firefox alone **BUT** here is the trick,  we came up with a simple jQuery plugin called [jquery-search- plugin](https://static1.kontaktkarte.de/js/jquery.clearsearch-1.0.4.js)

here is the snippet which will work for all the browsers

```js
$(function() {
    // init plugin (with callback)
    $('.clearable').clearSearch({ callback: function() { console.log("cleared"); } } );

    // update value
    $('.clearable').val('').change();
    
    // change width
    $('.clearable').width('200px').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://static1.kontaktkarte.de/js/jquery.clearsearch-1.0.4.js"></script>
<input class="clearable" type="text" placeholder="search">
```

might help you